# работа с Q в django и объединение QuerySet

Tags: python, django

Есть две модели `Orders` и `Clients`, при создании генерируется одинаковый `related_uuid` у каждой. То есть они так связаны. При поиске на сайте надо найти все вхождения в обоих моделях и вывести все `Orders` включая те, где `related_uuid` встречается в модели `Clients`.

**models.py**

```
class Orders(models.Model):

    device = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    related_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=22, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.device

class Clients(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    related_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=22, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
def getQuery(self):
    search_query = self.request.GET.get('filter')
    results_query1 = Orders.objects.filter(Q(device__icontains=search_query))
    results_query2 = Clients.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=search_query))
    conds = Q(related_uuid__icontains=results_query1) | Q(related_uuid__icontains=related_query2)
    search_filter_three = Orders.objects.filter(conds)
    return search_filter_three
```

1. то есть я ищу вхождения в обоих моделях
2. потом пытаюсь отобрать все входження в модели `Orders` по полю `related_uuid` с обоих моделей

**выводит ошибку `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
    results_query1 = Orders.objects.filter(device__icontains=search_query).values_list('related_uuid')
    results_query2 = Clients.objects.filter(name__icontains=search_query).values_list('related_uuid')
    conds = Q(related_uuid__in=results_query1) | Q(related_uuid__in=related_query2)
```

Думаю это то, что вам надо